# np.c_ converts data type to object. Can I prevent that?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, data-cleaning, numpy

Was trying my hand at the Titanic dataset, when I wanted to One Hot Encode a categorical feature, after which I wanted to combine the original data with the new one hot vectors. The datatypes are as such:

`data` : Pandas Dataframe

`Titles_ohe` : Numpy sparse matrix (float64)

I tried to merge them into a dataframe using `np.c_` :

`columns = (list(data))+list(Titles.values)`

`data = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[data.values, Titles_ohe.toarray()], columns=columns)`

However on checking the data type of the resulting Dataframe, all the attributes have been changed to the `object` datatype. Is there any way I can prevent this while using `np.c_`, or is there an alternative solution? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use DataFrame.join() in this case:

```
data = data.join(pd.SparseDataFrame(Titles_ohe, index=data.index, columns=Titles))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Could you tell me what the index attribute does? It’s not covered in the pandas documentation.

Comment: @SureshKasipandy, this simply sets the index values of the dataframe, that we are creating...